# How to change the UITableViewCell image on the left on the UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, xcode4.2, uibarbuttonitem

I am a newbie to iPhone programming. I am stuck in a situation. I need to change the `UITableViewCell` image (on the left side) through calling an action from `UIBarButtonItem` fromt he `UIToolBar`. I have searched through internet, but can't find any appropriate solution.

Any Help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: [cell.imageView setImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

Comment: show us code, and a screenshot (if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code for customizing cell imageView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{        
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      [cell.imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
      [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
      [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

      [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    }

    // customize cell
    [cell.imageView setImage:**your_image**];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:] method you can access a cell at a specific row. When you have accessed that you can reach the image by cell.imageView. Have a look at this:

```
- (IBAction)barbuttonPressed
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
    cell.imageView = ..... 
}
```

Replace row and section with appropriate.